# partitioning by year over historical data

Tags: sql-server

I cannot separate data between 2016 and 2017 using my partition clause

```
select *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY [Customer Number] ORDER BY [Week Ending]) FROM [dbo].[mytable]
```

My output is giving me this:

```
Week Ending        Customer Number
Apr  5 2017 12:00AM   11
Apr  6 2016 12:00AM   2
Apr 12 2017 12:00AM   11
Apr 13 2016 12:00AM   4
Apr 19 2017 12:00AM   11
Apr 20 2016 12:00AM   6
Apr 26 2017 12:00AM   11
Apr 27 2016 12:00AM   11
Aug  2 2017 12:00AM   9
Aug  3 2016 12:00AM   11
Aug  9 2017 12:00AM   11
```

Basically, I would like to count how many times Customer # appears partitioned on years 2016 and 2017

Answer (score 0):

Add the year to the partition by... and ideally the select too so you know what count goes with what year.

```
select 
    *, 
    TheYear = DATEPART(year,[Week Ending]),
    TheYearlyCount = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY [Customer Number], DATEPART(year,[Week Ending]) ORDER BY [Week Ending]) 
FROM [dbo].[mytable]
```

Comment: Glad this worked for you... [don't forget about this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)